# Java - two almost teh same methods with different return type

Tags: java

I wonder how can I avoid duplicating code in my example below. I have two methods where one of the parameters is slightly different and a little bit different object is returned (one of them - simple - has less object fields)

```
public class WarehouseSimpleSearchFilter {
    long companyId;
    private Set<Long> shipperIds;
    private Set<Long> carrierIds;
}
```

```
public class WarehouseSearchFilter extends WarehouseSimpleSearchFilter {
    long companyId;
    private String search;
    private Boolean isLocked;
}
```

```
private WarehouseSimpleSearchFilter getWarehouseSimpleSearchFilter(Set<Long> carrierIds, Set<Long> shipperIds, Authorization authorization, WarehouseSimpleSearchFilter searchFilter) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(carrierIds) && CollectionUtils.isEmpty(shipperIds)) {
            final Set<Long> newCarrierIds = getCompanyId(WarehousePermission.READ_AVAILABLE, authorization);
            final Set<Long> newShipperIds = getCompanyIds(WarehousePermission.READ_COMPANY, authorization);
            searchFilter.setCarrierIds(newCarrierIds);
            searchFilter.setShipperIds(newShipperIds);
            return searchFilter;
        }
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(carrierIds)) {
            checkPermission(WarehousePermission.READ_AVAILABLE, authorization);
            searchFilter.setCarrierIds(Collections.unmodifiableSet(carrierIds));
        }
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(shipperIds)) {
            checkPermission(WarehousePermission.READ_COMPANY, authorization);
            searchFilter.setShipperIds(Collections.unmodifiableSet(shipperIds));
        }
        return searchFilter;
    }

    private WarehouseSearchFilter getWarehouseSearchFilter(Set<Long> carrierIds, Set<Long> shipperIds, Authorization authorization, WarehouseSearchFilter searchFilter) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(carrierIds) && CollectionUtils.isEmpty(shipperIds)) {
            final Set<Long> newCarrierIds = getCompanyIds(WarehousePermission.READ_AVAILABLE, authorization);
            final Set<Long> newShipperIds = getCompanyIds(WarehousePermission.READ_COMPANY, authorization);
            searchFilter.setCarrierIds(newCarrierIds);
            searchFilter.setShipperIds(newShipperIds);
            return searchFilter;
        }
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(carrierIds)) {
            checkPermission(WarehousePermission.READ_AVAILABLE, authorization);
            searchFilter.setCarrierIds(Collections.unmodifiableSet(carrierIds));
        }
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(shipperIds)) {
            checkPermission(WarehousePermission.READ_COMPANY, authorization);
            searchFilter.setShipperIds(Collections.unmodifiableSet(shipperIds));
        }
        return searchFilter;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like these methods are identical but one of them operates on a subclass. You can use generics to write these in one go.

```
private <T extends WarehouseSimpleSearchFilter> T getWarehouseSimpleSearchFilter(
  Set<Long> carrierIds,
  Set<Long> shipperIds,
  Authorization authorization,
  T searchFilter
) {
  ...
}
```

However, there are a few things to note here.

First, it looks like you always just mutate the `searchFilter` argument and return it. If that's the case, you could just return `void` and take a `WarehouseSimpleSearchFilter` as argument. There's no sense in returning the same value you were passed in, unless you're designing a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) (and the argument in question is not the receiver in your example, so that doesn't apply here).

Second, I challenge the use of inheritance here. You have a parent class which seems to be a "simple" search filter, and then you subclass it to enrich functionality. This is a classic antipattern that used to be taught in schools, and your "simple" search filter is very likely to become a [fragile base class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class). Inheritance should model an "is-a" relationship. And while I can't see what methods are available on your search filter, the naming convention alone suggests to me that an "enriched" search filter is not, in fact, a simple search filter. It looks like you're using inheritance as a tool of implementation convenience, not to correctly model the object space.

Instead, I would suggest having an interface that represents the abstract API backing both the simple and enriched search filters. If there's significant common functionality between the two that *doesn't* depend on any specific state of the class, then it can be factored out into static methods somewhere or default methods on the interface itself. Then each of your search filter implementations can be implementors of that interface and your generic function can take an interface (or bounded generic of an interface, as above) as argument.

Comment: I have 2 return types because I have 2 a little bit different endpoints tha should return full data and limited data (simpleDto). So can I stil use inheritance like in my example?